# How to create a datatable with Yajra in a show laravel view?

Tags: laravel, datatables, yajra-datatable

I have the related models **Request** 1: M **Tasks** and I would like to show a datatable with yajra in the show view of the **requests**, that is to say that if I enter the show view of the request with ***id = 1*** it will show me a datatable filled only with the tasks related to the request ***id = 1***, I tried to return the datatable from the **show function** of the controller but I didn't know how to only get the tasks related to the request.

In any case, I don't know if this is of any use, but, this is how I make my datatable for the index of the tasks:

```
    public function taskData()
    {
    $tasks = Task::join('requests', 'requests.id', '=', 'tasks.request_id')
                    ->select('tasks.id', 'requests.code_request', 'tasks.fake_id',
                            'tasks.date');

    return Datatables::of($tasks)
            ->addColumn('btn', 'tasks.actions')
            ->rawColumns(['btn'])
            ->make(true);
    }
```

and then in my view:

```
<script>
   $(function() {
      $(document).ready(function(){
         // initializing Datatable
             var table = $("#tareas-table").DataTable({
                serverSide: true,
                pageLength: 10,
                ajax: '{!! route('datatables.tareas') !!}',
                columns: [
                   { data: 'fake_id', name: 'tareas.fake_id' },
                   { data: 'codigo_solicitud', name: 'solicituds.codigo_solicitud' },
                   { data: 'fecha_inicio', name: 'tareas.fecha_inicio' },
                   { data: 'estado', name: 'tareas.estado'  },
                   { data: 'btn', name: 'btn',orderable:false,serachable:false,sClass:'text-center' }
               ]
           });
        });
 </script>
```

thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `DataTableScopeContract` for that.

The docs have an example for that: https://datatables.yajrabox.com/services/scope

Comment: link down, but your info is very useful, thaks @Furkan

Comment: yes, I could enter through a vpn, even though I don't see how to apply it in frontend

Comment: Can you add your routing and HTTP Controller file into your post?